# Why my js code skip the first line of array when looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i want do make object from 2D array and the output only like this

```
{ firstName: 'd', lastName: 'e', gender: 'f' }
```

this is my code

```js
function x(y) {
  var z = {}

  for (a = 0; a < y.length; a++) {
    z.firstName = y[a][0]
    z.lastName = y[a][1]
    z.gender = y[a][2]
  }
  return z
}

var y = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"]
]
console.log(x(y))
```

what's wrong with this code? why it skip the first line of array when looping?

Comment: `z` is a single object, not an array. You're overwriting the properties each time through the loop.

Comment: @Barmar, you are right. I thought OP test the loop itself and found that the a is always the last one. But this could only happen in IE11.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return an array of objects, not a single object that you keep overwriting in the loop.

```js
function x(y) {
  var result = [];

  for (let a = 0; a < y.length; a++) {
    let z = {};
    z.firstName = y[a][0];
    z.lastName = y[a][1];
    z.gender = y[a][2];
    result.push(z);
  }
  return result;
}

var y = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"]
]
console.log(x(y))
```

You can also simplify it using `map()`.

```js
function x(y) {
  return y.map(i => ({
    firstName: i[0],
    lastName: i[1],
    gender: i[2]
  }));
}

var y = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"]
]
console.log(x(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are **overwriting** the property inside the object,

check the code snippet below

```js
function x(y) {
  const z = []
  
  for (let a = 0; a < y.length; a++) {
    z.push({
       firstName:y[a][0],
       lastName:y[a][1],
       gender:y[a][2],
    })
    
  }
  return z
}

var y = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"]
]
console.log(x(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the values of `z.firstName`, `z.lastName` and `z.gender` during your second loop, an object may not contain duplicate values

You should consider defining `z` as an array and using the `array.push()` method.